# Dropzone.js upload image path into DB

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am trying to upload a file path into my files table but with little success. I am using the dropzone.js lib to handle the drag and drop upload. I can successfully insert the file into an uploads file but I am struggling to get the path to create a row in the table:

Here is how I create the form:

```
<form action="actions/file-upload.php" class="dropzone">
<div class="fallback">
<input name="file" type="file" multiple />
</div>
</form> 

<?php
$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;  //1
$storeFolder = '../uploads';   //2

if (!empty($_FILES)) {

    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];          //3             
    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;  //4
    $targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name'];  //5
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile); //6


    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$targetFile)){
        //insert file information into db table
        $conn->query("INSERT INTO files (name) VALUES('$tempFile')");
    }


}
?>
```

I have sen similar threads on SO but nothing it glaringly obvious...

Comment: Are multiple files uploaded?

Comment: @guest271314 both single and multiple can be

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem (file uploaded into folder but not db). I solved this problem today with adding `Null` for Default Values into table rows in mysql db.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).